# How do I choose a default theme if the theme gives a white screen?

Tags: 7

I tried to make a folder templates for all tpl files but after that now I can not load my theme anymore on Xamp? Now when I try to load theme in drupal there was only white screen.What can I do?

I am tired of that so if you just make one mistake in Drupal, you are need to install again and again.

I choose a different theme and I close the browser, but the theme is not working. How can I load a different theme if I don't have access anymore to Drupal?

Comment: You are avoiding the problem by adding another theme ? This is terrible (IMO) solution. You are going to change the UX because you have a bug and do not know how to fixed it. That is really bad. I think the best solution is to look what is going wrong within your templates and fixed it.

Comment: [Drush command to change the theme in Drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727162/drush-command-to-change-the-theme-in-drupal). [Unusable Theme: How to Reset Your Theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/200774). Another tip is to make regular backups of your db so you can restore if need be, especially during development.

Answer (score 1):

You can update in database.

Change the active theme in the database

The default theme setting is stored in Drupal's database, and thus can be changed by manipulating the database from the command line or an administration overlay or client like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench for MySQL.

Always make a backup of your database before changing values in it directly, as it is possible to destroy data and render your site unrecoverable at the database level. You have been warned.

In Drupal 6 and 7, the setting is stored in the system table:

## activate a trusted theme

```
UPDATE system SET status=1 WHERE name = 'garland';
```

## change the default setting

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:7:"garland"' WHERE name = 'theme_default';
```

## clear the cache tables

```
TRUNCATE cache;
TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap;
TRUNCATE cache_block;
```

Another way

```
sites/default/settings.php:
$conf['theme_default'] = 'bartik';
```